# Как добавить checked элементу (jquery)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, песочница

Как добавить элементу псевдокласс checked на jquery?
Имеется проверка:

```
$( init );
  function init() {
    if ( $('.lang-de').hasClass('active');
}
```

Как дальше дописать этот скрипт, чтобы добавить нужному input псевдокласс checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исходя из исходного описания можно сделать как-то так:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('.lang-de').hasClass('active')) {
    $('input.needed').attr('checked', 'checked');
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="lang-de active">De</div>

<input type="checkbox" class="no-needed" />
<input type="checkbox" class="needed" />
```